# Sorting datastore item by auto_now=True and auto_now_add=True

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, mako

I am trying to sort an item in datastore by age by using `auto_now=True` and `auto_now_add=True`. I managed to solve `datetime` problems but I am unable to sort correctly by age. I appreciate any suggestions. (Sorry for the capitalized variables, I will fix them eventually.) My model is:

```
class Rep(db.Model):
    mAUTHOR = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user=True)
    mUNIQUE = db.StringProperty()
    mCOUNT = db.IntegerProperty()
    mDATE = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    mDATE0 = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    mWEIGHT = db.IntegerProperty()
    mAGE = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Query is:

```
    QUERY3 = Rep.all()
    QUERY3.filter("mAUTHOR =", user)
    QUERY3.order("mAGE")
    RESULTS3 = QUERY3.fetch(7)
```

And this is what I use in Mako template:

```
    % for result in RESULTS3:
        <% result.mAGE = int((result.mDATE - result.mDATE0).seconds) %>
        <p>${result.mUNIQUE} (${result.mCOUNT}) (${result.mAGE})</p>
    % endfor
```

And here's an example of output with bad sort:

```
mUNIQUE  mCOUNT  mAGE
A       (11)    (38604)
C       (19)    (5319)
D       (10)    (1797)
E       (17)    (2735)
F       (16)    (871)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, it looks like you're only calculating `mAGE` when you retrieve the records, i.e. *after* doing the query. Shouldn't you calculate it whenever you modify an object, before putting it into the datastore?

Before that, though, are you sure that it's what you want to do? `mAGE` will be the time between when you last modified each record, and when the record was created. That seems like an odd thing to sort on. If you want to sort by the actual age of the record (time since creation), use `mDATE0` to sort. Or if you want to sort by most recent changes, use `mDATE`.

To sort in reverse, use `QUERY3.order("-mDATE")` (note the hyphen).